# Backup SQL database on button click event using c# when using a web application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, webforms

I am making a web application as part of my college project which uses a database in SQL server.
Now, I want to backup the DB using c# code on button click event. I have tried searching, but have only found information on how to do a backup on demand manually. Not on button click event when the admin chooses to do so through a web page. Any help please?

Comment: you can call a procedure or task from sqlserver from within c# have you looked into it ? I looked on google and you can do a backup from transact sql like so : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server

Comment: create a stored procedure which does the backup, then call the stored procedure from your application on a button click.  You can do this by adding the database as a DataSource in visual studio, then importing your stored procedure.

Comment: So here is a post (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/) detailing how to programmatically backup a database. As for doing it on a button click from a web app, you will need to expose some sort of endpoint in your application that can be called from the web and have it execute the backup.

Comment: @Louis-RochTessier ofcourse backup can be done using tsql, but backup on button click event is something which I havent been able to find any info on.

Comment: @EMUEVIL Thanks for that, I need to try it out over the next few days, and I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: @Ken what exactly do you mean expose some sort of endpoint? can you explain this in layman terms, im new to programming

Comment: An endpoint would be something that can be called from outside of the system. For example a REST Service uses controllers and has url endpoints, you would use something like www.example.com/api/users to get a list of users.

Comment: Looking at all the answers mine included I have the feeling all that code showing the actual heavy lifting (connecting to database, finding the right .NET namespaces for this, exporting the data to a file, asf.) seem to be completely superfluous since I am under the expression the OP is just asking for this `private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var backupCreator = new FancyBackupCreationMechanism();
            backupCreator.doFancyBackup();
        }` and not caring a bit for all the ways we have come up with the `FancyBackupCreationMechanism`.

Comment: @Murty please specify what technology/framework you have in mind for setting up that website from which said button click event originates. Otherwise everybody is left to guess.

Comment: @SvenM. Its an ASP NET web application, using web forms. I have plenty of answers here. Ill try implementing them, and see how I get on. Thank you for your help, its appreciated.

Comment: @Ken the website will not actually be up and running as such on the cloud, its a project, and I will be submitting the code, with it. So no endpoint as such. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Murty ASP.NET WebForms it is? Right. I'll toss together a mini WebForms app showing you how to wire the button click event up there. Since I am on vacation might even throw in a docker container with a MySQL/MSSQLDb so we can go full circle.

Comment: @Murty `ASP.NET WebForms` project added to example and github repo. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

- Example project for exporting a database exists in a github repo: https://github.com/Rusk85/ExampleSqlBackupCreator
- It contains the exporter logic `SqlBackup` as a project
- It contains a `WinForms` project showing the usage of a button click event
- It contains a `WebForms` project showing the same button click event usage
- In addition there is a powershell script allowing to download a `Microsoft Sql Server 2016 Express` instance, automatically loading it up with your desired `database.mdf` file
  and then export it using one of the two GUI projects

---

I also came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835603/1352384) handling a very similar scenario.
There they are linking to this [site](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/) which is providing multiple methods of backing up a SQL Database from C# using [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup(v=sql.120).aspx) Namespace. I have not tried it myself but I think you might find all the information there you need.
I also went ahead and modified the code a bit adding the appropriate using statements.

I am assuming you have a `ConnectionString` for your SqlServer akin to this one: `Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

More exmaples can be found [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).
Just pass that connection string to the `DoBackup()` method and make sure you have specified in your connection string the keyword `Database`. The `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` will essentially parse that string and make parts of it accessible through its properties.

---

#### Docker Container added for `Microsoft Sql Server Express 2016`

As of right now there is a powershell script `run_sqlexpress_docker.ps1` with some variables that have to be set accordingly but once done automatically pulls the latest MSSQLExpress 2016 Server, downloads any user-specified `database.mdf` file and attaches it to the sql server instance running in the docker container.

**Todos as of know:**

[ ] Work the required parameters for the powershell script into the `WebForms` project

[ ] Run the powershell script from within the project after said variables are set

[ ] Then actually test the 'SqlBackupCreator' after allowing to parameterize some of the static file export fields

---

#### Button Click Event (`ASP.NET WebForms`)

*Now as for having this all happening with a click of a button I added the below class `_Default`, which shows just that. The whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/Rusk85/ExampleSqlBackupCreator).
I have to warn you though, I did not have a MSSQLDb to test this and while I was trying to make it work with MySql I just ran out of time. There also is little to no guarding when it comes to malformed `ConnectionStrings`. In other words the app will crash and burn fantastically in cases of that.
There also are static path references for the output file, which you will have to change accordingly.*
Interesting parts to watch out for:

- `btnStart.Click += btnClick_Start;` // wiring up the website button to a specific method
- `id="btnStart"` // giving the button a name so I can address it in the CodeBehind
- some more styling candy and stuff; really nothing impressing at all

Already pushed this to my github repo so you can clone it from there and have a got at it: https://github.com/Rusk85/ExampleSqlBackupCreator

---

#### WebForm-Project showing `Button Click Event`

This is the code of the `Default.aspx.cs`

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStart.Click += btnClick_Start; // registers the click event with the method below "btnClick_Start"
    }

    private void btnClick_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sqlBackupCreator = new SqlBackupCreator();
        var conStr = tbConStr.Text;
        sqlBackupCreator.DoBackup(conStr);
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the `Default.aspx` (at least the juicy bits; the rest is being created when you make a new project anyway)

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Clicking the button starts backing up the Database</h2>
        <p>

            <asp:TextBox
                runat="server" ID="tbConStr"
                placeholder="Connection String goes here (no validation)"
                Columns="129"/>
        </p>
        <div style="margin-left: 17.5em">
            <p>
                <asp:Button
                    id="btnStart"
                    runat="server"
                    Text="Start Backup"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

---

#### Button Click Event (`.NET WinForms`)

*Now as for having this all happening with a click of a button I added the below class `Form1`, which shows just that. The whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/Rusk85/ExampleSqlBackupCreator).
I have to warn you though, I did not have a MSSQLDb to test this and while I was trying to make it work with MySql I just ran out of time. There also is little to no guarding when it comes to malformed `ConnectionStrings`. In other words the app will crash and burn fantastically in cases of that.
There also are static path references for the output file, which you will have to change accordingly.*

---

You will also need to reference these Assemblies on which you can read up more on [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1826/getting-started-with-sql-server-management-objects-smo/):

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll

---

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SqlBackup.GUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sqlBackupCreator = new SqlBackupCreator();
            var conStr = tbConStr.Text;
            if (conStr == null)
                return;
            sqlBackupCreator.DoBackup(conStr);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace SqlBackup
{
    public class SqlBackupCreator
    {
        public static void DoBackup(string connectionString)
        {
            var sqlConStrBldrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
            var bkpDBFull = new Backup();
            /* Specify whether you want to back up database or files or log */
            bkpDBFull.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            /* Specify the name of the database to back up */
            bkpDBFull.Database = sqlConStrBldrBuilder.InitialCatalog;
            /* You can take backup on several media type (disk or tape), here I am
             * using File type and storing backup on the file system */
            bkpDBFull.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\AdventureWorksFull.bak", DeviceType.File);
            bkpDBFull.BackupSetName = "Adventureworks database Backup";
            bkpDBFull.BackupSetDescription = "Adventureworks database - Full Backup";
            /* You can specify the expiration date for your backup data
             * after that date backup data would not be relevant */
            bkpDBFull.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);

            /* You can specify Initialize = false (default) to create a new 
             * backup set which will be appended as last backup set on the media. You
             * can specify Initialize = true to make the backup as first set on the
             * medium and to overwrite any other existing backup sets if the all the
             * backup sets have expired and specified backup set name matches with
             * the name on the medium */
            bkpDBFull.Initialize = false;

            /* Wiring up events for progress monitoring */
            bkpDBFull.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
            bkpDBFull.Complete += Backup_Completed;

            /* SqlBackup method starts to take back up
             * You can also use SqlBackupAsync method to perform the backup 
             * operation asynchronously */
            var myServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(connectionString)));
            bkpDBFull.SqlBackup(myServer);
        }

        private static void CompletionStatusInPercent(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Percent completed: {0}%.", args.Percent);
        }

        private static void Backup_Completed(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hurray...Backup completed.");
            Console.WriteLine(args.Error.Message);
        }

        private static void Restore_Completed(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hurray...Restore completed.");
            Console.WriteLine(args.Error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Yes I do have the connection string, but how to do this on button click event?

Comment: @Murty Sorry was a bit in a hurry. So you have say a Forms Application with a Button that is supposed to trigger this? I wire something up for your quick.

Comment: @Murty I added the button click event and hosted the entire project on github ready for your consumption. See links and further information above.

Comment: Thanks. I need to try that and get back to you over the next week or so. Appreciated!

Comment: @Murty added `ASP.NET WinForms` example. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks! :) once I implement this, ill get back to you.

Comment: @Murty Also there is a docker container with a mssql instance you can run your tests on. Its not fully automated yet but getting there. Also in order to test this, there isn't much to implement. Just clone the github repository https://github.com/Rusk85/ExampleSqlBackupCreator and open it in your visual studio. You might have to jump one or two commits back bcause those are WIP. Oh and set the startup project accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers everyone. But I found an easier solution:

First, add the following in Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="connectionToSqlServer" 
connectionString="Your ConnectionString" (this is the connectionstring to 
the actual server where the DB is located, not the connectionstring to the 
DB)

providerName ="System.Data.SqlClient" />         
</connectionStrings>
```

Then, in the code behind:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

protected void btnBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conToDBString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionToSqlServer"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection conToDB = new SqlConnection(conToDBString);

        conToDB.Open();
        string str = "USE [NameOfDatabase];";
        string str1 = "BACKUP DATABASE [NameOfDatabase] TO DISK = 'C:\\Temp\\BackupForDB.bak' WITH FORMAT,MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',NAME = 'Full Backup of NameOfDatabase';";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str, conToDB);
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(str1, conToDB);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conToDB.Close();
    }
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: Yes that works as well as it basically boils down to using Sql Mgmt Server for exporting Databases and disregarding the rich feature-set MS offers to operate on their databases where they take into account things like security risks, performance, asf (here e.g. I am think SQL-Injection depending how this code is going to be used). But I am happy you have found a simple and straightforward solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want backup DB only, you can use T-SQL and standard SqlConnection and SqlCommand. I's faster and better way. See the MSDN[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql) for T-SQL backup syntax. You can use SQL Management Studio for generate T-SQL script for backup database (fill the Backup form and click Script button instead of run the backup).

Comment: ofcourse, but I want to do it on button click event

Comment: @Murty

`void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { // your backup code }`
See [this C# project](https://github.com/Rusk85/ExampleSqlBackupCreator) on how to do that with a `Windows Forms` Application.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we did backup / restore in a recent project. Copied from the original, should work out of the box.

You'll need these

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
```

...and this is the implementation

```
    protected static void BackupLocalDatabase(string serverInstance, string databaseName, string databaseBackupFileName)
    {
        var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(serverInstance);
        var server = new Server(serverConnection);

        try
        {
            if (server.Databases.Contains(databaseName) == false)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("database does not exist on server");
            }

            var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var description = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Backup of {0} on {1}", databaseName, timestamp);

            var backup = new Backup()
            {
                Database = databaseName,
                Action = BackupActionType.Database,
                BackupSetDescription = description,
                BackupSetName = description,
                Incremental = false
            };

            // delete any backup we already have
            if (File.Exists(databaseBackupFileName) == true)
            {
                File.Delete(databaseBackupFileName);
            }

            var device = new BackupDeviceItem(databaseBackupFileName, DeviceType.File);
            backup.Devices.Add(device);

            backup.PercentComplete += backup_PercentComplete;
            backup.SqlBackup(server);
            backup.PercentComplete -= backup_PercentComplete;

            serverConnection.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (SmoException ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("SmoException " + ex);
            throw;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("IOException " + ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    static void backup_PercentComplete(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("{0}", e.Message);
    }

    protected static bool CheckDatabaseExists(string serverInstance, string databaseName)
    {
        var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(serverInstance);
        var server = new Server(serverConnection);

        return server.Databases.Contains(databaseName);
    }

    protected static void RestoreLocalDatabase(string databaseBackupFileName, string destinationDirectory, string serverInstance, string databaseName)
    {
        var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(serverInstance);
        var server = new Server(serverConnection);

        Trace.TraceInformation("Restoring backup file {0} to database {1}", databaseBackupFileName, databaseName);

        try
        {
            // see if the database exists, and if it does, close it down and drop it
            if (server.Databases.Contains(databaseName))
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Database exists; killing active connections (there shouldn't be any)...");
                server.KillAllProcesses(databaseName);
                server.Databases[databaseName].Drop();
                Trace.TraceInformation("Active connections killed and database dropped.");
            }

            // set up the command
            var restore = new Restore()
            {
                PercentCompleteNotification = 10,
                Database = databaseName,
                NoRecovery = false,
                KeepReplication = false,
                ReplaceDatabase = true,
                Restart = true
            };
            restore.Devices.AddDevice(databaseBackupFileName, DeviceType.File);
            restore.PercentComplete += restore_PercentComplete;

            // relocate the source files from the backup to the local location
            var files = restore.ReadFileList(server);
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in files.Rows)
            {
                var physicalName = dataRow["PhysicalName"].ToString();
                var logicalName = dataRow["LogicalName"].ToString();
                physicalName = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, Path.GetFileName(physicalName));
                restore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalName, physicalName));

                Trace.TraceInformation("Relocating physical DB file {0} to physical file {1}", dataRow["LogicalName"].ToString(), physicalName);
            }

            // do the restore
            Trace.TraceInformation("Beginning restore...");

            restore.SqlRestore(server);
            restore.Wait();

            Trace.TraceInformation("Restore complete.");

            restore.PercentComplete -= restore_PercentComplete;

            // general database housekeeping
            Trace.TraceInformation("Shrinking database (just to be sure)...");
            server.Databases[databaseName].RecoveryModel = RecoveryModel.Simple;
            server.Databases[databaseName].Shrink(1, ShrinkMethod.TruncateOnly);
            Trace.TraceInformation("Shrink complete.");

            serverConnection.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (SmoException ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("SmoException " + ex);
            throw;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("IOException " + ex);
            throw;
        }

        Trace.TraceInformation("Completed restoration of backup file {0} to database {1}", databaseBackupFileName, databaseName);
    }

    static void restore_PercentComplete(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("{0}", e.Message);
    }
```

Comment: how to do this on button click event?

Comment: @Murty You do it like this `public void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { BackupLocalDatabase("serverInstance", "databaseName", "databaseBackupFileName"); }`. Of course all this is in the context of the GUI. For an example of that look at this complete [`C#.NET 4.6.2 Solution`](https://github.com/Rusk85/ExampleSqlBackupCreator).