# Why I can't save database backup on desktop?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-backups

I want get a backup from my SQL Server database in C# Windows Forms. But I have some problems. When I want to save the backup file with a different name of database, my app crashes and errors. Also I cannot save my backup on the desktop but all off the other location not having error.

This is my code for getting back up; I use `FolderBrowserDialog`, because any name other than the main name of the database is entered by the user, the program gets an error.

```
string result;

FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
BLLBackupRestore bLL = new BLLBackupRestore();

dialog.ShowDialog();

if (dialog.SelectedPath != "")
{
    result = bLL.backUp(dialog.SelectedPath);

    if (result == "true")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message.messageSettingBackUpDataBase(), "",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, 
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, message.messageBoxAlign());
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get when I try and save the backup on the desktop; there is no problem with any other address or folder.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open backup device 'C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\Custom_Category.bak'. Operating system error 5 (Access is denied.)
>
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at DataAccessLayer.BackUpRestor.backUp(String address) in C:\Users\sadegh\source\repos\Custom_Category\DataAccessLayer\BackUpRestore.cs:line 22
>
> ClientConnectionId:02e41dc3-d9b0-4c5c-baa1-089a79463b37
> Error Number:3201,State:1,Class:16

Comment: It's the database saving the backup so what matters is the permissions held by the database user, not the user executing your app. That user obviously does not have access to your desktop.

Comment: Note that, if you use SSMS to create or load a backup, you won't be able to access the desktop of Documents folder or the like for the same reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to backup Sql Database Programmatically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835553/how-to-backup-sql-database-programmatically-in-c-sharp)

Comment: thank you i going to read this right now.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server BACKUP is an internal Transact SQL command nammed BACKUP ... (like a query) and is executed by SQL engine under the permissions assigned to the SQL Server service account (a Windows user).

You try to use a path for the backup that is reserved to another Windows user which is "sadegh". The SQL Server service account does not have any permissions to write into your reserved location.